# Angular material components is not working inside `Material Dialog`

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using `mat-form-field`, `mat-dialog-close` and `ng-model` properties inside dialog box. But its throwing error saying its not known property of input/button.

> title-dialog.html

```html
<h1 mat-dialog-title></h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p>Enter Column Name</p>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.animal" />
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <br />
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.animal" cdkFocusInitial>
    Ok
  </button>
</div>
```

> MyComponent.ts

```js
import {
    Component,
    OnInit,
    Input,
    OnChanges,
    Output,
    EventEmitter
} from '@angular/core';
import {
    Inject
} from '@angular/core';
import {
    MatDialog,
    MatDialogRef,
    MAT_DIALOG_DATA
} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {
    MatTableDataSource
} from '@angular/material/table';
import {
    MatSnackBar
} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-test',
    templateUrl: './test.html',
    styleUrls: ['./test.scss'],
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    animal: string;
    constructor() {}
    ngOnInit(): void { this.openDialog(); }

    openDialog(): void {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(TitleDialogComponent, {
            width: '250px',
            data: {
                animal: this.animal
            }
        });

        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            console.log('The dialog was closed');
            console.log(result);
        });
    }


}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-title-dialog',
    templateUrl: './title-dialog.html'
})
export class TitleDialogComponent {

    constructor(
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef < TitleDialogComponent > ,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data) {}

    onNoClick(): void {
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }

}
```

Am I missing anything here? I have included all material imports in `app.module.ts` and its working fine in other components.

Getting these errors

[image]

> Edit 1:

I am importing my material components here

> Material.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import {MatSnackBarModule} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatStepperModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatDialogModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatStepperModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatDialogModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

I have only one module no submodules and  my `app.module.ts` is

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from '../app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MyComponent} from '../components/home/home.component';
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { RangeSelectionDirective } from '../components/range-selection.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    RangeSelectionDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MaterialModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FlexLayoutModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: can you reproduce this issue in stackblitz.com?

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your module imports?

Comment: You miss imports in the respective module (you need them in every module that uses them, even if the module is a submodule of  your  app.module). E.g. ngModel needs FormsModule.

Comment: @ArunkumarRamasamy I couldn't replicate the issue in stackblitz

Comment: @lionbigcat  I have Edited the question with imports plz check

Comment: @GunnarB. Can you please verify my imports?  Couldn't identify the issue

Comment: `MyComponent` and `TitleDialogComponent` are not part of AppModule but a sub module, is that correct? If so, that sub module needs those imports too. If multiple modules need the same imports, it's a good idea to create a `shared module` that does all the imports and exports everything again. Then every module that needs something from that shared module, just has to import the shared module.

Comment: @GunnarB. No. I have only one module. No sub modules. I just renamed the compoent to MyComponent here bcz I was having project specific name for my component

Comment: The `TitleDialogComponent` also needs to be in the `entryComponents` list of the module by the way. (Aside from declarations.)

Comment: @GunnarB. I thought `entryComponents` got deprecated in the move to Ivy?  I've been taking that out of all my module declarations now that I'm running Angular 10...

Comment: @Coderer interesting. I didn't know that. entryComponents is not needed anymore since Angular 9.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: Just noticed that your `TitleDialogComponent` is not declared in your `AppModule`. That's probably the main reason -.-

In `app.module.ts`,

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    RangeSelectionDirective,
    TitleDialogComponent // <------- Add this
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MaterialModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FlexLayoutModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

For the below: still better to add a reference. Though the above should be enough to solve your problem.

Your module imports seem correct. That said, it's clear from the error messages that `TitleDialogComponent` is not registering any of the modules. My guess to the problem, without a stackblitz to play around with, is the way you open the Modal.

Try referencing the target modal as a property of its parent Component, like so:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    animal: string;
    titleDialogRef: MatDialogRef<TitleDialogComponent>; // <------ Added this
    constructor() {}
    ngOnInit(): void { this.openDialog(); }

    openDialog(): void {
        // Assign to titleDialogRef instead
        this.titleDialogRef = this.dialog.open(TitleDialogComponent, {
            width: '250px',
            data: {
                animal: this.animal
            }
        });

        this.titleDialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            console.log('The dialog was closed');
            console.log(result);
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: Adding `TitleDialogComponent ` to `app.module` fixed the issue..  Thanks a ton